# How to share a folder with only 1 user on 1 computer over the network?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, file-sharing

I have two computers, both running windows 10. I have a folder on one computer, called "desktop" for this question, which I would like to be able to access from my other computer, called "laptop". Unfortunately, all I can do is share the folder with all computers on the network, which I do not want to do. What I have done so far is go into folder -> properties -> sharing -> advanced sharing -> permissions -> add. In this box, I have tried pressing on "locations", however, only "desktop" shows up. I should be able to see "laptop" as well, and select my user account on "laptop" Why am I only able to share folders on a single computer or with every computer on the network?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if I share the folder with myself (my user account on desktop), I can access it on the network with my desktop account credentials, or if I have an account with the same username and password, I can just access it. I will not accept this answer in case someone else comes up with something that's conducive to sanity.